# How to do visible component if backend refresh token success

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

Method in authService, which send request to backend server and get response as json with access token

```
 refresh() {
        if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')) !== null && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')) !== undefined) {
          const body = ...
          let headers = ...
          return this.http.post(this.authUrl, body.toString(), {
            headers
          });
        }
      }
```

Method which above works correctly

In navbar component haves button:

```
<button mat-menu-item (click)="addTrip()" *ngIf="isLogged()">
  <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
  <span>add Trip</span>
</button>
```

which must be visible only if exist token in localStorage and if this token isn't expired

The method isLogged doesn't work as needed. Call subscribe this.auth.refresh.subscribe(..... return true or false ? ...) is impossible, because subscribe is unsynchronized method. How in first to get token and after return boolean value?

```
 isLogged() {
   if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')) !== null && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')) !== undefined)   {
     this.auth.refresh();
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: 1. Create AuthService file. In that create a variable of BehaviourSubject. 
2. Make the api call and on success trigger the `.next()` of the BehaviourSubject. 
3. In your component import the AuthService and listen to the changes of behaviour subject.

Comment: @AnuraagDJain But how can I refresh the token, if now the access token is expired in the component? I must call the method from authService and get true or false after success or unsuccess result from request to back server, but I can't do this, because I can set up value only if check the response via subscribe.

Comment: I hope your server will tell you that access token is expired. In that scenario, you must implement `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` to capture the exact error message and make a new request to get the new token / logout the user and redirect to `/login` page.